# select only rows with finite values in data.frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Imagine I have a `data.frame` with many columns in R. I would like to select rows only where *all* of the columns have finite values.

```
set.seed(123)
d = data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:10, Inf, -Inf), 100, replace=T), ncol=20))
```

I don't want to refer to each column by name since there are a lot of them. `na.omit` and `complete.cases` wont' do the trick here.

One way to do it is to run:

```
d[apply(apply(d, 2, is.finite), 1, all),]
```

This is ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it only integers in the data.frame, or are there factors and character vectors as well?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: say its `numeric`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
d[is.finite(rowSums(d)), ]
```

Comment: He said select only rows, not select only columns.

Comment: @eddi: Nice trick. It may fail in some reaaaly rare situations: `matrix(.Machine$double.xmax, ncol=2)` :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft you're right of course about overflow - one way around it is to use `rowMeans` instead of `rowSums`

Comment: There's also `do.call(pmin,abs(dd))`, which remains finite.